# Quarkus rest client(w/o CompletionStage): calling 2 endpoints in order, how to define return type to have better performance

Tags: java, multithreading, quarkus-rest-client, completion-stage

In Quarkus, rest client can be defined to return my DTO, or CompletionStage.

I have 2 endpoints to call, first I want to retrieve some `JobDTO` from endpoint 1, then update it and save it back using 2nd endpoint.

I observed that:

- If I define both endpoints returning `CompletionStage<JobDTO>`, main thread will initialize `executor-thread-0` to call endpoint 1, and then `executor-thread-0` hands over the work to `executor-thread-1` to call endpoint 2
- If I define 1st to return `CompletionStage<JobDTO>`, then 2nd endpoint to return `JobDTO`, only `executor-thread-0` is used, 2nd endpoint call happens on it too.

I know that in this case, by default, `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` is used.

So, which is better? It's blocking I/O operation so I guess it's better to only block 1 thread if API call is slow; however I am not sure how the work stealing pool works, when I/O blocking happens.

For example if I define both to return `CompletionStage`, and 1st endpoint returns fast, `executor-thread-0` will quickly hand over work
to `executor-thread-1`. Then, will `executor-thread-0` fetch more work and hands it over to `executor-thread-2` to cause more threads blocking? Or it still hands to `executor-thread-1` and queuing there?

Do I have to calculate the latency of these 2 endpoints and do some calculation, and then use some custom ExecutorService?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out.

If you define some different CompletionStage yourself, you need to provide the executor service, like in [this blog](https://nurkiewicz.com/2015/11/which-thread-executes.html); each stage needs one, so you may end up with multiple.

But the work of calling the endpoint when return type is `CompletionStage` will use Quarkus rest client pool, which can be configured by some properties as mentioned [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/19251). For example, I can configure `quarkus.rest-client."my-api".connection-pool-size`. This key is found in `io.quarkus.restclient.config.RestClientConfig`, among many others.

Of course if I define both endpoint to return `CompletionStage`, they will run in this above pool.

I think I will still block on one thread in this pool instead of splitting the work into 2 threads.